# Dynamically add object in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have json:

```
var obj = '{"Form":[],"Provider":[]}';
```

I push the data with variable value to make dynamic objects:

```
var pName = 'Tester';
var data = {
    pName :["testing"]
};
console.log(obj['Provider'].push(data));
```

But that adds pName as variable name but not variable value that is **Tester**, i tried with +pName+ that also not works.

Returns:

```
{"Form":[],"Provider":[{"pName":["Testing"]}]}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You cannot take a property such as `Provider` of a JSON string; you must first convert the string into a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse()` (or specify it as a JavaScript object literal to start with).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `[]` syntax near the property name.It will evaluate the expression in the `[]` and returns the value.

See the example.Here the `data's` property is with the name `'Tester'`.

```js
var obj = {"Form":[],"Provider":[]};

var pName = 'Tester';
var data = {
    [pName] :["testing"]
};

console.log(data.pName); // undefined
console.log(data.Tester); // OK

obj['Provider'].push(data);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I am about to answer this one. Haha. Great job sir. Cheers!

Comment: if you're going to introduce the `[keyname]: value` syntax, you should at least give the proper name for this construct. Also, to be precise, this syntax does not "return" the value; it **uses** the value as the key name. Finally, you omitted any mention of the OP's issue with trying to manipulate a JSON string without converting it into a JavaScript object first.